# Certificate chain check failed with errors

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509certificate

Trying to check certificate trust chain:

openssl verify -CAfile DEVICE_ROOT.pem device.crt

Gout output:

```
C = EST, ST = Tallin, L = Tallin, O = COMPANY NAME, CN = 0000000330 DEVICE CERT
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
device.crt: verification failed
C05A0000:error:16000069:STORE routines:ossl_store_get0_loader_int:unregistered scheme:crypto\store\store_register.c:237:scheme=file
C05A0000:error:80000002:system library:file_open:No such file or directory:providers\implementations\storemgmt\file_store.c:267:calling stat(C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL/certs)
C05A0000:error:16000069:STORE routines:ossl_store_get0_loader_int:unregistered scheme:crypto\store\store_register.c:237:scheme=C
C05A0000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:inner_loader_fetch:unsupported:crypto\store\store_meth.c:383:No store loader found. For standard store loaders you need at least one of the default or base providers available. Did you forget to load them? Info: Global default library context, Scheme (C : 0), Properties (<null>)
```

How to know reason trust chain failed?